# /django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed/ after python manage.py migrate app zero

Tags: python, django, django-models, migration, django-migrations

I had some mess with migrations in production and localy. Finally the situation was that in production there were only initial migration and localy there were 8 migrations or something. So I decided to use

```
python manage.py migrate app zero
```

both in production and localy(django 1.8.7). In prodcution it worked but locally it raised error which didn't appear before after `makemigrations` or `migrate` command.

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: app_userprofile__new.phone_number
```

after few attempts to try different things, the error began to appear after migrate commands too.

The model itself :

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    phone_number = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your local database.

This error usually happens when one or more records do not meet the NOT NULL requirement

```
    UserProfile.objects.filter(phone_number=None)
```

You can resolve this by filling the phone_number field of the objects found

Or deleting objects that do not have filled phone_number

**UPDATE**

Manage database changes with `database migrations` can prevent this type of situation

Comment: yeah, deleting some very old records helped the situation. could you please also say whether what I am doing with migrations issue is correct? or at least not harmful?

Comment: You have not performed incorrect procedures from my point of view. Old data can cause this type of error when new constraints are established.

Comment: why does it think the field is NOT NULL? blank=True should take care of this, no? Is there something I can say in the model definition to take care of this?

Comment: @sureshvv in the case (or when it occurs to me) is because a field that was not initially mandatory, happens to be after some change.

If it is NOT NULL from the beginning it will not go through this.

Comment: database migrations can prevent this type of situation as well

Comment: @Guilhere.. Thanks.. Adding null=True to field defn. helped me overcome this error